# Unable to install IE11 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

Windows 7 64-bit SP1 EN-US - installation package meets all requirements, downloaded and installed all Windows updates. Getting "Internet Explorer did not finish installing" error and link to troubleshooting page.

Comment: Have you check the installation log for specific errors?  You are currently running with IE10 installed correct?

Comment: Have you tried downloading it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40292) ? Do you have latest SP or updates ?

Comment: Same result. Yes, all latest updates installed.

Comment: Where can I find installation log? For now I have IE9 installed.

Comment: If its anything like IE10 on Windows 7 the two logs would be located at `c:\windows\logs`

Comment: upload the CBS log files

Comment: Okay, I have two log files related to IE11 setup. First one is hardware check log which returned 0x00000000 value in all checks. Second one is NR_Setup which contains several warnings:  WARNING ________ IESetup environment variable is predefined as 'C:\Windows\TEMP\IE1D6FD.tmp\IE11-support'

Comment: did you get a fix for it?

Answer (score 3):

Review the IE11_main.log file in the \Windows folder. This log file has information about each installation and is appended for each subsequent installation.

Comment: okay, here it is:  Launched package installation: C:\Windows\SysNative\dism.exe /online /add-package /packagepath:C:\Windows\TEMP\IE15931.tmp\IE11-neutral.Extracted.cab /quiet /norestart
00:21.684: INFO:    Process exit code 0x00000002 (2) [The system cannot find the file specified. ]
00:21.715: ERROR:   Neutral package installation failed (exit code = 0x00000002 (2)).

Answer (score 1):

This is how i was able to fix my issue with installing IE11. Copied from a different forum.

Uninstall IE10 restart

Uninstall IE9 restart

Run the following command at an elevated command prompt:

`FORFILES /P %WINDIR%\servicing\Packages /M Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-*~11.*.mum /c “cmd /c echo Uninstalling package @fname && start /w pkgmgr /up:@fname /norestart”`

**Restart** - *IMPORTANT

Go to:

Start_Control Panel_Programs_Programs and Features_Turn Windows Features On or Off.

You should see a list of programs with check boxes to their left. Make sure you see Internet Explorer 8 listed. If you see Internet Explorer 8 listed you should be able to install the Internet Explorer Standalone Update found here:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie-11-worldwide-languages

Comment: Before running this command my features showed Internet Explorer 11 even though 11 was not installed successfully and I had uninstalled back to IE8. The command did not work per answer giving error 'ERROR: Files of type "Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-11..mut" not found. I instead ran `FORFILES /P %WINDIR%\servicing\Packages /M Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-*~11.*.mum /c “cmd /c echo Uninstalling package @fname && start /w pkgmgr /up:@fname /norestart”` and it ran successfully and uninstalled those packages. Now Windows Features shows IE8 but still same error installing IE11.

Comment: FIXED! I forgot to RESTART the PC after running command and before trying to reinstall IE11. After rebooting it installed correctly! I believe my problem was from a previous install of IE11 that was rolled back to IE10 because of incompatibility with previous versions of intranet web applications.

Answer (score 0):

I have had several systems that never updated to IE9 or 10 correctly and therefore would fail when updating to IE11 with the Neutral Package failure.

I have resolved these failures by changing the date on the system to 1/1/2012 and then reinstalling IE9.  Once it installs successfully, then installing IE11.  In each case, I have resolved the issue.

The problem is that the certificate on the Neutral Package in IE9 or 10 is out of date, so changing the clock back to a time before the cert expires allows the package to install properly.  I am amazed that Microsoft Support does not even know this, I figured it out by mistake when I selected one of the files in the .CAB file and decided to look at the certificate and saw it was expired.

Comment: I'm trying your suggestion, but can't find IE9 for Windows 7 x64. I downloaded a version for Vista, but that didn't install on my computer. Then I downloaded IE10, which refuses to install because there is a newer version of IE installed on my system. I guess this only works when you have not updated to IE11 yet?!

Answer (score 0):

Just to update [Michael B's excellent answer](https://superuser.com/a/750584/345355) for if the [IE11_main.log file](https://superuser.com/a/690559/345355) shows a "Neutral package installation failed" error: an IE9 installer is no longer available for Windows 7, but you can find links for IE10 [here](https://superuser.com/a/837402/345355), and installing this version after setting your clock to 1/1/2012 still works great.

For those of you that already have IE10 or IE11 installed, you can find instructions for how to downgrade down to IE9 here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043971/how-to-downgrade-from-internet-explorer-11-to-internet-explorer-10