# Does Microsoft still have a link to download IE10 for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-10

Does Microsoft still have a link to download IE10 for Windows 7?

I can find it off of OldApps.com but not off of a Microsoft site.

My coworker needs it to test something, and doesn't have a VM readily available.

Comment: https://www.modern.ie/

Comment: I read the licenses, and didn't think that the modern.ie VMs were free for corporate use

Comment: IANAL, however the whole purpose of that site is to provide VMs for testing IE.  I'm pretty sure the license means the VM OS is not to be used for commercial purposes, just for testing.

Comment: In IE you can hit F12 for developer tools, click the bottom icon on the left(emulation), and switch the document mode in the dropdown box to emulate different versions of IE.

Comment: yeah maybe i read it a bit too literally @heavyd

Comment: after you've been burned by the developer tools a couple times, you realize that they aren't worth it @DanHogan

Comment: Check: [IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9, IE10, IE11 Offline Installers Download Links](http://www.itechtics.com/download-internet-explorer-all-versions/)

Comment: Did not find in the given links, but found here: http://filehippo.com/download_internet_explorer_windows_7_64/14435/

Comment: [Win7 VMs with IE 8, 9, 10, 11](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try these Microsoft offline installer links:

- [Internet Explorer 10 (32-bit)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/A/C/8AC7C482-BC74-492E-B978-7ED04900CEDE/IE10-Windows6.1-x86-en-us.exe)  *... no longer works (09/11/2016)*
- [Internet Explorer 10 (64-bit)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/E/0/CE0AB8AE-E6B7-43F7-9290-F8EB0EA54FB5/IE10-Windows6.1-x64-en-us.exe)  *... no longer works (09/11/2016)*

These may refuse to work if you already have IE 11 installed, though.

If it is refused, try this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043971/how-to-downgrade-from-internet-explorer-11-to-internet-explorer-10

And in case these links ever stop working and you must obtain a copy from a non-Microsoft source, here are the SHA-512 hashes for posterity:

- 32-bit: d89ba3f9978be428ac05b182481198ab0f7b0c0651e4716e63cd0cf907d739cbc30f44ec9c444da683869473a548cd99e5c396467b2898f7c382b6345b3e70d2
- 64-bit: f1752bb6517fe15071e5f7a4fee4b8680da1bdad1df7054ab22bab78fe0f46aee177787f60ea2cfc86a2db2b08429e2cba3cfdd20ba6a2ab69e091c7784dfdae

Comment: Do you have a link to a landing page? not sure how you found these

Comment: I searched for "internet explorer 10 offline installer" or something like that. I don't think MS really intends to make IE 10 available anymore, so they probably took down any landing pages.

Comment: The first link is for the Windows 7 32-bit edition, the second link for Windows 7 64-bit edition. I first thought the bit version refers to Internet Explorer.

Comment: @Nick Actually, the bits do refer to IE. 32-bit Windows can only run 32-bit IE, but 64-bit Windows can run either (or even both at the same time).

Comment: [I'm not so sure about the "offline" part.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MLREn.png)

Comment: worth noting that you can use web.archive.org to get them with those links.

Answer (score 8):

FWIW, there is an excellent Irish site (modern.ie) that has virtual machine (VM) images (VMWare and Virtual Box) with IE versions all the way back to IE6. Excellent for testers!
https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools

Comment: +1 for insisting on the integrity of the country code system

Comment: "an excellent Irish site" - brilliant!